# Why HTML helper class is referred as Html instead of HtmlHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razorengine

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) documentation for `HtmlHelper` class, thing that surprised me was, it was used in asp.net code as:

```
@Html.Action("Contact me","contact");
```

instead of

```
@HtmlHelper.Action("Contact me","contact");
```

As documentation has `HtmlHelper` as name of class then why we use it as `Html` only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to how the `Model` variable is available inside of your view - even though you haven't directly defined a `Model` variable yourself - Razor is generating a class that provides these instances of your model type and `HtmlHelper` in the scope of your cshtml file. It generates a method on that class which writes HTML according to the contents of your cshtml file.

`Model` is an instance of the type specified by the `@model` directive, provided in the scope of your cshtml file when the generated method is called and having been passed as the argument to the `View` method in one of your actions.

`Html` is an instance of type `HtmlHelper`, provided in the scope of your csthml file by the generated class.

`Url` is an instance of type `UrlHelper`.